# how to show in the view a object and the attribute of another table

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, object

Well, I am using laravel, I have two tables, one for users and the other for roles, and I am showing in a view a table with each user with their attributes and also the role they have associated. the problem is that the attribute is the id, and what is shown is the id of the role table, how can I show the role name instead of the id?

This is the function where I get the list of users:

```
public function index()
{

    $users = User::latest()->get();
    return view('users.index', [
        'users'=>$users,
    ]);
}
```

and this is the view where I build a table to show the attributes, and in the role_id attribute, I only have the number associated with the role table. when I really need to show the name.

```
            @foreach($users as $user)
                <tr>
                    <td>{{$user->name}}</td>
                    <td>{{$user->last_name}}</td>
                    <td>{{$user->age}}</td>
                    <td>{{$user->DOB}}</td>
                    <td>{{$user->height}}</td>
                    <td>{{$user->role_id}}</td>
                    <td><a href="{{$user->path_edit()}}">Edit</a> <a href="/users/{{$user->id}}/destroy" > - Delete </a></td>

                </tr>
            @endforeach
```

This is the database :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Make a relation to your user with role table. Write the below code in your user model

```
    public function role()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Role::class);
    }
```

Use it in your view file

```
<td>{{$user->role->name}}</td>
```

Comment: More information about relations here: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships

Comment: You also need to check attribute name which used to interconnect the models. You can specify them explicitly like that:
```$this->belongsTo(Role::class, 'role_id', 'id'); ```